# Convert Python String to Dictionary

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I have a string:

```
A = "{user_id:34dd833,category:secondary,items:camera,type:sg_ser}"
```

I need to convert it to python dictionary, so that:

```
A = {"user_id":"34dd833", "category": "secondary", "items": "camera", "type": "sg_ser"}
```

On top of that, there are two more issues:

1: the "items" key is supposed to have multiple values, like:

```
A = {"user_id":34dd833, "category": "secondary", "items": "camera,vcr,dvd", "type": "sg_ser"}
```

Which apparently comes into the form of a string as:

```
A = "{user_id:34dd833,category:secondary,items:camera,vcr,dvd,type:sg_ser}"
```

So, generalizing anything based on comma separation becomes useless.

2: The order of the string can be random as well. So, the string can be like this as well:

```
A = "{category:secondary,type:sg_ser,user_id:34dd833,items:camera,vcr,dvd}"
```

Which makes any the process of assuming thins by order as a false one.

What to do in such a situation? Many thanks.

Comment: What kind of value is that `34dd833` in your intended output? Did you mean to put that in quotes? Or prefix it with 0x? Or something different?

Comment: ohh..I am sorry..it is supposed to be a string..let me update the question.

Comment: Why does your input look like this? Where does it come from? I'm pretty sure this isn't valid JSON.

Comment: It comes from an external source that I need to parse..unfortunately, I dont have any control or access on modifying its generation process.

Comment: What external source? What's the format? It's going to be pretty ugly parsing `items:camera,vcr,dvd,type:sg_ser` and recognizing that `type` isn't part of the value of `items`.

Comment: This is a hideous format.

Comment: Someone else posted a question a few months ago with effectively the same format, which implies that someone out there is serving up horrible data like that. (Maybe just to keep Stack Overflow busy?)

Comment: @user2357112: You can tell that `type` isn't part of the value of `items` because it's the last thing before the `:`, meaning it's a key instead. Yes, it's a bad format, but it's not an ambiguous one.

Comment: the source is an external database and the data is accessible from an url (api).. :-/

Comment: This definitely isn't JSON. If you think it's supposed to be, maybe you're reading it wrong (e.g., maybe you're trying to parse the `__str__` representation of the data instead of the data itself?). If not, you should remove the `json` tag.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If we can assume that your input doesn't do any quoting or escaping (your *example* doesn't, but that doesn't necessarily mean it's a good assumption), and that you can never have comma-separated multiple keys, just multiple values (which probably *is* a good assumption, because otherwise the format is ambiguous…):

First, let's drop the braces, then split on colons:

```
>>> A = "{user_id:34dd833,category:secondary,items:camera,vcr,dvd,type:sg_ser}"
>>> A[1:-1].split(':')
['user_id', '34dd833,category', 'secondary,items', 'camera,vcr,dvd,type', 'sg_ser']
```

So the first entry is the first key, the last entry is the last value(s), and every entry in between is the Nth value(s) followed by a comma followed by the N+1th key. There may be other commas there, but the last one always splits the Nth value(s) from the N+1th key. (And that even works for N=0—there are no commas, so the last comma splits nothing from the 0th key. But it doesn't work for the very last entry, unfortunately. I'll get to that later.)

There are ways we could make this brief, but let's write that out explicitly as code first, so you understand how it works.

```
>>> d = {}
>>> entries = A[1:-1].split(':')
>>> for i in range(len(entries)-1):
...     key = entries[i].rpartition(',')[-1]
...     value = entries[i+1].rpartition(',')[0]
...     d[key] = value
```

This is almost right:

```
>>> d
{'category': 'secondary', 'items': 'camera,vcr,dvd', 'type': '', 'user_id': '34dd833'}
```

As mentioned above, it doesn't work for the last one. It should be obvious why; if not, see what `rpartition(',')` returns for the last value. You can patch that up manually, or just cheat by packing an extra `,` on the end (`entries = (A[1:-1] + ',').split(':')`). But if you think about it, if you just `rsplit` instead of `rpartition`, then `[0]` does the right thing. So let's do that instead.

So, how can we clean this up a bit?

First let's transform `entries` into a list of adjacent pairs. Now, each for each pair `(n, nplus1)`, `n.rpartition(',')[-1]` is the key, and `nplus1.rsplit(',', 1)[0]` is the corresponding value. So:

```
>>> A = "{user_id:34dd833,category:secondary,items:camera,vcr,dvd,type:sg_ser}"
>>> entries = A[1:-1].split(':')
>>> adjpairs = zip(entries, entries[1:])
>>> d = {k.rpartition(',')[-1]: v.rsplit(',', 1)[0] for k, v in adjpairs}
```

Comment: It should be `v.rsplit(',', 1)[0]` in the last line, otherwise you only get "camera" in the items.

Comment: @PauloAlmeida: Thanks! Notice that I got it right in the description above. And I also got it right in my local ipython. And this is exactly why you should always copy-and-paste, then clean up, instead of cleaning up while copying. :)

Comment: @abarnert I managed to butcher a monstrosity of a regex, but I like this ;)

Comment: @JonClements: IIRC, there was a similar question a few months ago, someone pasted a regex solution that was full of backtracks (making it exponentially slow if given bad data), and that also generated JSON to parse instead of just parsing the data directly. So, yours is not a monstrosity relative to what it easily could have been…

Comment: @abarnert I'm fairly sure there's something elegant and understandable that could be done with `pyparsing`

Answer (score 2):

Here's another way (not particularly robust, but shows it's possible on the sample data):

```
import re
text = "{user_id:34dd833,category:secondary,items:camera,vcr,dvd,type:sg_ser}"
print dict(re.findall(r'(\w+):(.*?)(?=(?:,\w+:)|$)', text.strip('{}')))
# {'category': 'secondary', 'items': 'camera,vcr,dvd', 'user_id': '34dd833', 'type': 'sg_ser'}
```